# How can i jump from child stack navigator to parent stack navigator specific screen in react native

Tags: nested, navigation, stack

I am using react native navigation version 6 in my project.
I have a nested stack .
Parent Stack is

```
<NavigationContainer >
      <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Authcation" component={Authcation} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AppIntroduction" component={AppIntroduction} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Registeration" component={Registeration} />
      <Stack.Screen name="RegisterationStack" component={RegisterationStack} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

here RegisterationStack  is another stack that hold screens

```
<NavigationContainer
            
            
            independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
               


                </Stack.Navigator>
                
            </NavigationContainer>
```

What I want is that when a user is on the login screen and presses the button login I want to navigate him to (Parent Stack) Home screen.

Note: Both of them are stack navigators as it is a use case . I can't use bottom tab or drawer stack

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
`isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
);
```

You can reference react navigation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)